# Changing mp3 songs in a queue Python,Pygame,Mutagen,Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pygame, mutagen

I am new to python and I'm trying to build a music player which can add all mp3 songs to its list in that folder.

I can see all the songs in a list , But when i click next button it only goes one song next and one song previous. if i click next again it plays the same song again. Is there anyway I can fix my code

I THINK there is something wrong in the methods , nextsong,prevsong. Please help I've tried alot but couldn't find where the error was

```
import os


import pygame
from tkinter.filedialog import Tk, Button, askdirectory, Label, Listbox, LEFT, RIGHT

from mutagen.id3 import ID3


root = Tk()


listofsongs=[]
formattedlist = []
realnames = []

index =0


def directorychoose():
    filename = askdirectory()
    os.chdir(filename)

    for file in os.listdir(filename):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            realdir = os.path.realpath(file)
            audio = ID3(realdir)
            realnames.append(audio['TIT2'].text[0])
            listofsongs.append(file)



    for file in realnames:
        formattedlist.append(file+"\n")

    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(listofsongs[0])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()


def nextsong(event):
    pygame.mixer.music.load(listofsongs[index+1])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

def prevsong(event):
    pygame.mixer.music.load(listofsongs[index-1])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

def stopsong(event):
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()

directorychoose()

label = Label(root,text='Music player')
label.pack()

listbox = Listbox(root)

listbox.pack()
for item in formattedlist:
    listbox.insert(0,item)

button = Button(root,text='Next')
button.pack(side=LEFT)
button2 = Button(root,text='Prev')
button2.pack(side=RIGHT)
stopbutton = Button(root,text='Stop')
stopbutton.pack()

button.bind("<Button-1>",nextsong)
button2.bind("<Button-1>",prevsong)
stopbutton.bind("<Button-1>",stopsong)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never assigned the change to index, so it's never changing. In addition this must be placed as a global variable since the variables within the functions are created and destroyed within them.

You are doing this:

```
x+1
```

And you should change it to:

```
x= x+1
```

**Complete code:**

```
import os


import pygame
from tkinter.filedialog import Tk, Button, askdirectory, Label, Listbox, LEFT, RIGHT

from mutagen.id3 import ID3

root = Tk()

listofsongs = []
formattedlist = []
realnames = []

index = 0

def directorychoose():
    filename = askdirectory()
    os.chdir(filename)

    for file in os.listdir(filename):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            realdir = os.path.realpath(file)
            audio = ID3(realdir)
            realnames.append(audio['TIT2'].text[0])
            listofsongs.append(file)

    for file in realnames:
        formattedlist.append(file + "\n")

    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(listofsongs[0])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()


def nextsong(event):
    global index
    index += 1
    pygame.mixer.music.load(listofsongs[index])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()


def prevsong(event):
    global index
    index -= 1
    pygame.mixer.music.load(listofsongs[index])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()


def stopsong(event):
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()


directorychoose()

label = Label(root, text='Music player')
label.pack()

listbox = Listbox(root)

listbox.pack()
for item in formattedlist:
    listbox.insert(0, item)

button = Button(root, text='Next')
button.pack(side=LEFT)
button2 = Button(root, text='Prev')
button2.pack(side=RIGHT)
stopbutton = Button(root, text='Stop')
stopbutton.pack()

button.bind("<Button-1>", nextsong)
button2.bind("<Button-1>", prevsong)
stopbutton.bind("<Button-1>", stopsong)

root.mainloop()
```